# How come fflush(stdin) function is not working?

Tags: c, string, scanf, fflush

My main question is why is it that the fflush(stdin); function not working? 
Whenever I run the the code, I am not able to get the second input with space ex. Hello World but instead I get Hello?? thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){

    int      x;
    double   y;
    char     string[100];

     /*

      * string input

      */

     printf("Enter one word: ");
     scanf("%s", string);  // note there is no & before string */
     printf("The word you entered was >>%s<<\n");

     printf("Enter many words: ");
     fflush(stdin); // <---- for some reason this function is not working
     scanf("%[^\n]", string); // read up to a newline (multiple words)

     printf("The text you entered was >>%s<<\n");

     getchar();   
}
```

Comment: See [flushing input streams](http://c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html).

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `fflush(stdin)`. It has do do with a missing parameter.  See below.  (get the second parameter in, then you can do some formatting work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior. `fflush()` is only defined by the C standard for output streams, and update streams where the last operation was an output.

Comment: On POSIX-derived systems, `fflush(stdin)` has undefined behavior. On Windows-based systems, the behavior is documented by Microsoft, it discards any data already in the input buffer.

Comment: It's still undefined according to the C language, whatever platform you're on, and the OP gives no details about his implementation anyway. The behavior of `fflush()` on input streams is undefined according to the standard, not implementation-defined, so from a standard C perspective it's always an error, even if the implementation defines a meaningful behavior for it.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - agree with your statement, and it does address the stated problem, but the real issue is two-part, neither of them contributed to by mis-use of `fflush()`  1) The code in the problem description area does not match what OP is _actually_ using, it will get runtime error. 2) (related to the first) if `printf()` has additional parameter `string`, code runs. and runs as OP has described it should.

Answer (score 1):

If you get any output at all, it would be because the code you have displayed in the problem description area, is not the code you are actually using.

Regarding your statement:
*I am not able to get the second input with space ex. Hello World but instead I get Hello??*.
Without the additional parameter in the `printf()` statement, you will get no output, and a runtime error.

The line (both places) `printf("The word you entered was >>%s<<\n");`  needs another parameter, add `,string`, like this:

```
 printf("The text you entered was >>%s<<\n", string);
```

That will fix your problem.

***Here is output*** after adding the parameter `string` in `printf()` (and *not* removing `fflush()`)
[image]
Apparently, `fflush(stdin);` is not really the issue here, at least for stated problem?

Comment: thanks for the clarification but that doesn't fix the main issue, An array name is already an address to the first element so i don't think i need another parameter?  let me know if I am wrong..