# Verification with strlen in c

Tags: c, string, loops, strlen

I am using this strip of code to verify the length being inputted in the struct so that the file wont explode but I do not think I am executing it right.

```
    do
    {
        inputflag=0;
        printf("Passenger ID no: ");
        gets(newRes.idCard);
        if((strlen(newRes.idCard))>7)
        {
            printf("invalid input \n");
            inputflag=1;
        }
        fflush(stdin);
    } while(inputflag==0);
```

Comment: Don't use `fflush(stdin)`.  It is illicit and causes undefined behavior!

Comment: By the time you check the size of input, the damage has already been done... Try using fgets instead.

Comment: even worse without  **fflush(stdin)**

Comment: You would be well-served to find the prototype for `gets()` in your implementation headers and comment it out. It is so vile and evil it has been deprecated from the language and will no longer be supported in future versions. Use [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: Your fflush should be on stdout after the print.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `gets` call is unsafe. It can accept more characters than you have allocated. Boom.

Assuming you have allocated at least 8 bytes for `.idCard` (i.e. 7 chars plus terminator) then consider using this:

```
  fgets(newRes.idCard, 7+1, stdin);
```

This ensures you will not accept too many chars.  It will truncate as necessary.  Check the return value of `fgets` for success.

(`man fgets`)

Compile this example code and study.  I hope you find what you're looking for in here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_ID_LEN (7)

int main() {
    char idCard[MAX_ID_LEN+1];
    printf("ID: ");
    if (fgets(idCard, MAX_ID_LEN+1, stdin)) {
        char *cLast = idCard + strlen(idCard)-1;
        if (*cLast == '\n')
            *cLast = 0;  // strip newline *if* present
        printf("Success!  idCard='%s'\n", idCard);
    } else {
        printf("Failure.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note there are several lines of code there to check if the input includes a newline char and remove it.  `fgets` ensures a newline *unless* the user entered more than 7 characters for the ID.  I hope this is clear for you.

Alternatively, this is probably less distracting for you:  (just use `fscanf`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char idCard[7+1];
    printf("ID: ");
    fscanf(stdin, "%7s", idCard);
    printf("idCard='%s'\n", idCard);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3052741, please share the code or snippet you tried.  `fgets` will stop reading upon newline.

Comment: '  do
        {
          inputflag=0;
    printf("Passenger ID no: ");
    fgets(newRes.idCard, 7+1, stdin);

       if((strlen(newRes.idCard))>7)
    {
   printf("invalid input \n");
   inputflag=1;
       }
    fflush(stdin);

        }while(inputflag==0);'

Comment: That's because fflush doesn't work as expected. Look at my answer how to flush stdin.

Comment: I think one also needs to force null-termination on the resulting string - if the number of characters read in is > 7, the value of idCard will not be null-terminated.

Comment: @user3052741, I just edited my answer above to include a small test program.  I suggest you compile and run that to confirm it works. It will. Please note there is no need for any `strlen` check for valid length anymore if you use `fgets` since max len is already ensured.

Comment: fgets will make sure that there is a 0 byte.

Comment: thx heeps @DarrenStone it worked :) and on top of all i understanded the method .

Comment: @user3052741, that's great. I just added another example that uses `fscanf` -- you could consider that method also.

Answer (score 3):

In order to properly flush stdin you should the following:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

And instead of `gets` you should use [fgets](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/) because there you can limit the number of characters to the size of your input buffer.

`gets` will not know the length and thus if the user enters more than the buffer provides, a buffer overflow can be caused.

[How come fflush(stdin) function is not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610319/how-come-fflushstdin-function-is-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Checking the length *after*  reading data into too small a buffer is too late.  Read the data into a large holding buffer first.

`fgets()` is a great replacement for the obsolete `gets()`.  Remember to strip a potential ending `\n`.

Also avoid magic numbers like '7'.  Use something like `sizeof(newRes.idCard)`.

In well designed code `fflush(stdin)` is not needed and should be avoided as it is not portable.

```
int inputflag = 0;  // Not clear is OP needs this value after the while loop.
do {
  printf("Passenger ID no: ");
  char buf[sizeof(newRes.idCard) * 2]; ' twice as big as needed.
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
    inputflag = 1;
    break;
  }
  size_t Len = strlen(buf);
  if (Len && buf[Len-1] == '\n') buf[--Len] = '\0';
  if(Len >= sizeof(newRes.idCard)) {
    printf("invalid input \n");
    inputflag = 1;
  }
  else {
    strcpy(newRes.idCard, buf);
  }
} while (inputflag == 0);
```